# In angular 8, How to drag/drop the content from one component into another component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng2-dragula

1st problem
- Drag the content from the one component list and drop the content into another component and content will not be dropped into particular position.
2nd problem
- when drag the content from one position to another position then original state of draggable not be stable.

When Using angular-2 draggable then that issue arise
https://github.com/isaacplmann/ngx-tour/issues/182

when using ng2-dragula then that issues arise
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/issues/965
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/issues/885

- Drag the content from the one component list and drop the content into another component and content should dropped into particular position.
  2nd problem
- when drag the content from one position to another position then original state of draggable should be stable.